# How to run old .bin file?

Tags: linux, software-rec

I'm trying to run this: http://fullrecall.com , but when I download, extract and run (using ./fullrecall-linux.bin after chmod +x) I get this error:

```
./fullrecall-linux.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1
```

Comment: So [what happened](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/555101/edit) when you tried the `apt-get`? Did the install work? Does the program run?

Comment: It appears to be a 32-bit binary - are you running a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS?

Comment: Using aptget didn't help, I already had the package installed. I'm running Ubuntu 19.04, 64bit

Comment: You'll need to have the 32-bit versions of the required share libraries installed.